# How can I change the state of checkboxs from a gridview in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox, gridview, row

I have a gridview on an aspx page (WebForm) that has item name and checkbox. In the code behind in c#, I get a list of items names and I want that the checkboxes next to the items I already have will be checked.

I know to find the checkbox using  `(CheckBox)row.FindControl("CheckBox1")`, but the `Checked` method doesn't work on it. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, there are 2 possible cases.

For a templated column, say like this Gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" Width="40%" GridLines="None"
    CssClass="table table-hover table-striped">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkActive" runat="server"
                    Checked='<%# Eval("Active") %>'
                    />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        GridView1.DataSource = 
            General.MyRst("SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA ORDER BY HotelName");
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

The result is this:

[image]

So, to get all rows checked, then this code:

```
    protected void cmdGetChecked_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox ckActive = (CheckBox)gRow.FindControl("chkActive");
            if (ckActive.Checked)
            {
                Debug.Print($"Row index check = {gRow.RowIndex}");
                int PK = (int)GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"];
                Debug.Print($"Database PK id = {PK}");
            }
        }
    }
```

And to say check all rows, then this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox ckActive = (CheckBox)gRow.FindControl("chkActive");
            ckActive.Checked = true;
        }
    }
```

However, you might have a case in which the column is NOT a templated field.

For "non" templated columns, we use the cells[] colleciton.

Say this GV.

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" 
            CssClass="table table-striped">

        </asp:GridView>
```

And say this data source

```
        GridView2.DataSource =
            General.MyRst(
                @"SELECT ID, City, HotelName, Active FROM tblHotelsA
                ORDER BY HotelName");
        GridView2.DataBind();
```

So, now renders as this:

[image]

So, most columns, the value can be had with cell[column number].Text

However, for a check box, you have to go one deeper.

eg this:

```
        foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView2.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox ckActive = (CheckBox)gRow.Cells[3].Controls[0] ;
            if (ckActive.Checked)
                Debug.Print($"Row checked = {gRow.RowIndex}");
        }
```

So, you have to use cell[column].Controls[0] to pluck out the check box, and then get the .checked value of that checkbox.

## Edit: So, user is to select or "check" the boxes

So, it stands to reason with the above examples, it is rather easy to allow the user to check box any row. To THEN process the check boxes, we use the above same code and concpets.

So, say this markup:

```
<h3>Select Hotels</h3>
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    DataKeyNames="ID" Width="40%" GridLines="None"
    CssClass="table table-hover table-striped">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="FirstName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName" HeaderText="LastName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="City" HeaderText="City" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName" HeaderText="HotelName" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Active" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkSel" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="cmdSel" runat="server" Text="Show Checked"
    CssClass="btn"
    OnClick="cmdSel_Click"
    />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
```

And then the button code for above is now this:

```
    protected void cmdSel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string PKDataList = "";
        foreach (GridViewRow gRow in GridView1.Rows)
        {
            CheckBox ckActive = (CheckBox)gRow.FindControl("chkSel");
            if (ckActive.Checked)
            {
                string PKID = GridView1.DataKeys[gRow.RowIndex]["ID"].ToString();
                if (PKDataList != "")
                    PKDataList += ",";

                PKDataList += PKID;
            }
        }

        string strSQL = $"SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA WHERE ID IN ({PKDataList})";
        DataTable dtSelected = General.MyRst(strSQL);

        Label1.Text = $@"id list selected = {PKDataList} <br/>
                      Rows selected = {dtSelected.Rows.Count}";
    }
```

The results look like this:

[image]

Comment: The thing is I don't have a bool value in my datasource. I have the full list of all items, and in the gridview I added a checkbox so the user can mark the items he want and then I make a list out of it. I have a list of items the user already have, and I want those items to be already checked in the checkbox next to them.

Comment: Right, but all my of posted code will still work the same. The grabbing of the check box from the row during processing is how you do this. See my edit, it should have been clear and easy then as to how "in general" you approach this problem. Anyway, see my edit and note again how the check box processing is done. It does not matter if the check box is driven by the database, or not - you can still always process the value of the check box control for each row. As noted, see my edit and 2nd example. The code really work the same anyway.